# UWP Continuous Integration: How to automatically execute my test part inside of my Unit Test APP by MSTest commandline

Tags: unit-testing, uwp, continuous-integration, mstest, gitlab-ci

My Universal Windows Application now is able to deploy and I try to associate my gitlab `CI` service to it,But failed to execute the test part automatically with MSTest commandline, which is separated from UWP and work as an Unit Test Application.

I had found so many solutions,telling me such as: `Package` my app Firstly before using the `vstest.console` command line to test(Cannot continuous integrate I guess), Making my Test APP and use the project's `.dll`files ,as the `testcontainer`, to test(Actually I cannot found out the `.dll` file)

What should I do next If I want to integrate APP with automatically testing part?

Here is the environment:

- Windows 10 OS
- Visual Stdio 2017(Includes Windows_10_14393 SDK)
- GitLab + Windows Runner(same environment as PC)
- Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.27309.0

And my DOM in Solution:

--+-- APP Solution

------+---APP1(University Windows Application)

------+---TestAPP1(Unit Test Application)

Answer (score -1):

You have to just build the test pan p in Release mode and use the `.appxreciepe` as argument to run `vstest.console`. no need to build an appx package